# Number of SURF features normally used?

Tags: image-classification, feature-engineering

I am interesting in knowing an approximate amount of [SURF features](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speeded_up_robust_features) used to do e.g. image-recognition on 224x224x3 images. Is there a standard amount of features used? Or perhaps a well-acclaimed article using SURF features that I could look at? I am not going to work with the features, but I am just trying to understand some aspects of their usage.